# Match parent only if children exists in xpath

Tags: xpath

```
('//div[contains(@class, "myClass")]') //all the occurrences
```

I need to select from those only the ones that have a div inside with the class "tec", also the `<div class="tec">` is a grandchildren of `<div class="myClass">`

Just in case:

```
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="other-div1"></div>
    <div class="sibling">
        <div class="tec">"Content."</div>
        <div class="other-div2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the ones that have the div that contain "Content."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is wondering how i fixed it, i used `//div[@class = 'class1'][div[( @class = 'class2') or (@class = 'class3')]//div[@class = 'class4']/div[@class = 'tec']]` i had to figure it out since the document changed a lil bit :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way :

```
//div[contains(@class, "myClass") and */div[@class="tec"]]
```

above xpath adds checking if current `<div class="myClass">` has grand-child `<div class="tec">` (use `contains()` instead of exact match `=` if you like).

You may want to switch to descendant axis if you're not sure where the `<div class="tec">` is located within  `<div class="myClass">`. In this case, don't forget the leading `.` to make the descendant axis relative to current `<div class="myClass">` context :

```
//div[contains(@class, "myClass") and .//div[@class="tec"]]
```

Comment: sorry mate, didn't have much time to try it out, i added my own answer, hope it doesnt bother you